# php permissions for execute only and not redable

Tags: php, permissions

I have some pho files which when executed triggers an api of an sms server which further sends sms.
These php files are triggered by another server with data like mobile no and msg.
Now these files are hosted an simple shared server. what permissions should be give to the folder and files so that it is not readable by public but gets triggered/executed by server. The files contains credentials to other services (like sms gateways) and hence needs to be safeguard.

what i tried is giving 711 to folder so that it becomes secret to public.
now for files 644 or 711 which is better option.
or there should be some thing else to be done.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX permissions distinguish between read/write/execute permissions for **user, group and other**. "Other" does not mean "public", it has nothing to do with that.

A UNIX process runs under a specific *user*, i.e. if you log in and run a program it runs under your user name, the Apache process typically runs as the user `daemon` etc. Each user can belong to one of more *groups*. That's the two things the user and group permissions pertain to. The "other" refers to user processes which do not fit either the user or group.

E.g., this file:

```
-rwxrw-r--  1 root  admin  5069718 Apr  6 14:52 /foo/bar/baz
```

is *readable, writable and executable* by the `root` user and *readable and writable* by any user in the `admin` group. Any user which is not either `root` or in the `admin` group has only *read access* to the file. That's what "other" refers to.

It's all just about the user the process runs at, it's not about "things on the computer vs. website visitors". "Website visitors" is not a concept covered by UNIX permissions.

Since Apache typically runs as `daemon`, make the files owned by `daemon` or at least the group `daemon` and make them *readable and executable* for this user and/or group. If *Apache* needs write permissions to certain files or directories, also selectively enable write access when needed (for example, log files). Whether a *URL* and therefore a script is accessible publicly via HTTP is controlled by Apache, not by UNIX permissions.

Comment: thank you. i made it 400 for files and 711 for folders, it works for the execution of file and deliver results as wanted post execution.
Now as you suggested working on http, the files is also available to the external user as http link only. so if we prevent url view it would not work for the server as well.